# Which way can I avoid Dropbox syncing older files when restoring a CloneZilla image?

Tags: dropbox, disk-image, clonezilla

Is there a way to avoid Dropbox Syncing older files back to my account when restoring a CloneZilla system image?

Comment: Dropbox keeps a history of your files for 30 days by default, and if you have a pro account, file histories [can be stored indefinitely](https://www.dropbox.com/help/11). You can always just revert to an older version if it syncs over the version you want. Otherwise just disable your internet connection and turn off dropbox/change its default location.

Comment: While restoring my system image and dropbox, dropbox will resync the outdated files and folders back to my dropbox account, thus replacing newer files with the one's located into the previous system backup. All I want to know, is how can I avoid this from happening.

Comment: How would dropbox sync from your account if you're not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

[Unlinking the computer from your account](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/25) should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to remove the old files and and then resync the current files back to your restored computer.

---

Dropbox computes file hashes to determine if a file has changed. Your old files will have a different hash than the new ones you do not wish to overwrite.

One way to do this is:

1. Boot into safe mode and **disable** (not stop) the Dropbox service.
2. Restart and Boot normally and then delete all of the files in your dropbox
   folder.
3. Start the Dropbox service and allow it to resync.

Comment: Resync could take a long time if you download remotely. If you have a local sync of DropBox, perhaps you can modify the steps and copy over the more recent files from a local source before starting up the Dropbox service.

Answer (score -1):

1. Unplug the network cable.
2. Restore from Clonezilla.
3. Delete 'old' files in dropbox folder.
4. Plug network cable back in to resync dropbox.